# How do I write to a file using Glib (C)?

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I'm trying to save data to a file using glib, but it doesn't want to write. It can still create the file. It also seems when it creates the file, and tries to write to that created file pointer, the program just crashes...

The relevant code:

```
#include "save.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GFile *save;
GFileIOStream *stream;

void initSave() {
    char *home = "", *fmt = "%s/.ProgSave.%d", *saveStr = "";
    #ifdef _WIN32
        home = getenv("USERPROFILE");
    #else
        home = getenv("HOME");
    #endif
    saveStr = g_strdup_printf(fmt, home, 123);
    save = g_file_new_for_path(saveStr);
    stream = g_file_open_readwrite(save, NULL, NULL);
    if (!stream) {
        stream = g_file_create_readwrite(save, G_FILE_CREATE_NONE, NULL, NULL);
    }
    g_free(saveStr);
}

void closeSave() {
    g_io_stream_close(G_IO_STREAM(stream), NULL, NULL);
    g_object_unref(stream);
    g_object_unref(save);
}

void writeWin() {
    g_output_stream_write(G_OUTPUT_STREAM(stream), "true", 5, NULL, NULL);
    g_output_stream_flush(G_OUTPUT_STREAM(stream), NULL, NULL);
}

bool getWin() {
    char line[5];
    gsize bytesRead;
    g_input_stream_read_all(G_INPUT_STREAM(stream), line, 5, &bytesRead, NULL, NULL);
    if (strcmp(line, "true") == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you want is write some data to a file with a known path using glib? If so I have what you need, and I will post an answer after confirmation

Comment: @Vladouch correct.

Comment: I have double checked and the function I have does the writing using the standard fputs/fputc, however I have a function that reads the contents of a file using GLib functions, will that be helpful?

Comment: @Vladouch I was only using GLib because the rest of my program is using GTK. I'm fine with using fputs/c, and reading using glib is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my way of approaching the problem!
To write to a file and to read from it

```c
    void write_to_file(const char *name)
    {
        // Beg of file
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(name, "w");
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("error\n");
        }
        // Write to the file here fputc('c', file);
    
        fclose(file);
    }
    
    int read_file(const char *path)
    {
        GFile *file;
    
        file = g_file_new_for_path(path);
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            g_print("file null\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
        GBytes *file_bytes = g_file_load_bytes(file, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (file_bytes == NULL)
        {
            g_print("bytes null\n");
            return 1;
        }
        size_t data_size = 0;
        char *pointer = g_bytes_get_data(file_bytes, &data_size);
        if (pointer == NULL)
        {
            g_print("pointer null\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
        {
            //Do the reading directly on the pointer to the bytes of the file
        }
        
        free(pointer);
        g_object_unref(file);
        return 0;
    }
```